# WebSocket upgrade in jetty-7.6

Tags: jetty, cometd

I am using CometD server and deploying it in jetty. I am using CometDv2.5.1 and Jettyv7.6. I just want to know how does websocket upgrade happens.

Does jetty have any upgrade filter ? If yes than when it is doing the upgrade ?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade on [Jetty 7 is typically done within a Servlet](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-7.6.16.v20140903/jetty-websocket/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketServlet.java), not a filter.  There also exists a [Handler version](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-7.6.16.v20140903/jetty-websocket/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketHandler.java).

Upgrade on Jetty 8 is the same.

Upgrade on Jetty 9:

- if using JSR-356 (aka javax.websocket), then it is done internally, before all servlet processing.
- if using the Jetty WebSocket API, then you can use a [Servlet](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/WebSocketServlet.html), [Filter](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/server/WebSocketUpgradeFilter.html), or [Handler](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/server/WebSocketHandler.html).

The Jetty 9 WebSocket API's filter is the most capable (from a path mapping perspective)

Comment: In jetty-7 if I specify my local filters in web.xml, they will be called first before the upgrade happens?

Comment: With jetty-9 if I use Jetty websocket APIs: Here is websocket upgrade filter will be the first one or not like javax.webscoket ?

Comment: If you use Jetty-9 native Jetty WebSocket APIs, then its totally up to you how to wire up the filters or servlets.  There is nothing about the native API that is automatic (unlike the jsr356 api).  With that said, Anuj, there are 3rd party libraries out there that expect the WebSocketUpgradeFilter to be wired up by Jetty (that's a jsr356-ism, not a Jetty Native WebSocket API concept), simply because hooking into a filter is easier than dynamically adding servlets.